# Is there a way to direct users to specific document libraries based on their login credentials?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, document-library

I am developing a Staff Appraisal site for the school I teach in. The idea is for each staff member to have a document library with their appraisal documents securely contained by permissions. We have 100+ teaching staff, so lots of libraries!

Is there a way to automatically redirect a teacher to **their** library when they log in based on their login credentials? I could do this via clicking through a staff directory but the Principal is keen for a personalized experience so when a user logs in they get a welcome message like "Good Morning Dave," and their library opens without having to click anywhere else.

My guess would be to set up a page with code snippets that do the redirecting - does this sound right? I don't know how to code at all, but the IT guys at school should be able to help me out if I can show them the idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Auto redirecting to a document library is not a bad idea. With code you can do anything.

You have to keep below things in mind to make it fully functional

1. You should name document libraries predictable. i.e. **Dave-Appraisal-Lib**. If you have more people with same name, then think of a logic to add numbers with name. This will help you in constructing URLs.
2. You can add a **Content Editor Webpart** on home page
3. Write JSOM code functions, and call it from `$(document).ready`. Function can contain code of getting the logged in user name such as `_spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName` this will help you in predicting library name
4. Construct your URL to Document Library, and then redirect.

Comment: Assuming all names are uniqe maybe name the libraries with their names and then code a simple javascript redirect that would use either what Asad here suggested or use [SPServices' get current user](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/utilities/SPGetCurrentUser.html)